EvalML: AutoML search keeps crashing the kernel
I am running automl search with EvalML version 0.83.0. The following code from the tutorial works.
X, y = evalml.demos.load_breast_cancer()
automl_with_ensembling = AutoMLSearch(
  X_train=X, y_train=y,
  problem_type="binary",
  max_batches=5)
automl_with_ensembling.search()

However, once I replaced the training data X and y with my own data. The kernel keeps dying.

The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

I've checked my training data, which doesn't contain nan or infinite numbers. One critical observation is the search can finish successfully with max_batches=1 but only random forest will be in the search results. As long as it is greater than 1, the kernel crashes.
Because it crashes the kernel without reporting errors. I have no clue what went wrong.
Any tips on this challenging problem? Cheers!
